# Send element to the background in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

If you try to put a comment on my product without being logged in, a container appears for you to login. 
The problem is that the container of related products also appears on that screen, sometimes covering the login form.

To test it, enter this URL and try to put a comment, you don't have to write anything:
https://vaporlibre.com/producto/neon-lime-ivg/

I have used these code snippets without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("p.wc-product-reviews-pro-form-submit-row button").click(function(){
$( '.product_image_wrapper').css("position","static !important");
});
$(":button.woocommerce-form-login__submit").click(function(){
$( '.et_pb_column').css("position","relative");
});
});
</script>
```

```
.et_pb_column {

    position: static !important;
}
```

```
$("p.wc-product-reviews-pro-form-submit-row button").click(function(){

                $( '.product_image_wrapper').css("position","static !important");

            });




            $(":button.woocommerce-form-login__submit").click(function(){

                $( '.et_pb_column').css("position","relative");

            });
```

I also leave a photo to make it easier to see it:

(https://subefotos.com/ver/?505a48dba89f4acd38638dad0dcb414fo.png
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set a `z-index` of `1` to the row that contains your related products.

You can either enter the following in your stylesheet:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .et_pb_row_3_tb_body {
    z-index: 1 !important;
  }
</style>
```

Or if you need to configure it using JavaScript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.et_pb_row_3_tb_body').css('z-index', 1);
  });
</script>
```

I'd also suggest to give an `id` to this `div` so it's easier to target it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, but I'm sorry to say that that did not work, neither the css nor the javascript

Comment: @JavierMuñozSánchez Weird, it's working for me (added the CSS rule from Chrome's devtools). Are you sure your stylesheets are loading correctly? I can't seem to find the `z-index` rule anywhere.

Comment: Excuse me, I tried it and when it didn't work I eliminated it; now I have put it back, but it still doesn't work, I also tried javascript without results. Thanks

Comment: @JavierMuñozSánchez I see that you've re-added the CSS rule now. [It looks alright](https://imgur.com/a/wRx0ybt) on my browser. Isn't that the expected result? Does it look different on your browser?

Comment: I put it in my CSS stylesheet without success, then I remembered that I did that with a visual constructor, added it there and it worked. Thank you very much and forgive my clumsiness, now it works perfectly.